# Error when executing maxent algorithm with categorical variable

Tags: raster, r, maxent, dismo

I tried to use maxent algorithm where I have categorical variable as follow :

```
mod <- dismo::maxent(x=env, ## env conditions ( rasterstack)
                     p=Pre_final,   ##(SpatialpointsDataFrame)
                     a=bg_ALL, #(SpatialpointsDataFrame)
                     args = c('outputformat=cloglog',
                         'autofeature=true',
                         # 'linear=false',
                         # 'quadratic=false',
                         # 'product=false',
                         'threshold=false',
                         # 'hinge=false',
                         'betamultiplier=1',
                         'responsecurves=true',
                         'jackknife=true',
                         'writeplotdata=true',
                         'askoverwrite=false',
                         'writebackgroundpredictions=true',
                         'writemess=false'),
                       factors='Cartes_distances_Routes'
  )
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Error in [.data.frame(x, , f) : undefined columns selected
```

When I remove the argument "factors" I turn it without errors but I have to declare the categorical variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but specifying the categorical variable by its index number (in the stack), not by its name, did the trick.